# jQuery UI - tooltip for dynamic generated button

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

How can I make the jQuery UI tooltip  work for dynamic generated buttons?

HTML dynamic generated

```
<button class="make_entry" title="make an entry>   click here   </button>
```

JS

```
 $(document).tooltip();
```

Comment: how are you adding the buttons on page.

Comment: with an angular js template

Comment: You need to rebind the method after adding the content.

Comment: Ignore what @user2952265 said, it seems to be off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must instantiate the tooltip on the button after adding it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="some-div">
    <button class="add-me">Add another dynamic button!</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.add-me').on('click', function () {
    $('.some-div').append('<button class="make_entry" title="make an entry"> click here   </button>');
    $('.make_entry').tooltip({
        content: "Awesome title!"
    });
});
```

P.s. you don't have to specify `content` at all as it will then use the `title` attribute as the tooltip content.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/trvjazkf/